# How can I improve an imutable wiki page which has no talk page?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

[This Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe?action=show&redirect=KernelTeam%2FCrashdumpRecipe) has an issue. Under 'Inspecting the crash dump using crash' it says to add some repos and keys, but after that I still get NO_PUBKEY errors from apt-get update. Where should I go to tell someone who can edit the page about this?

Comment: Maybe you could sign up here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kernel-team and convey your observation.